# Hide or Display specific tabs in tabBar in react-native using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, tabs, navigation, hide, react-navigation

When creating Bottom Tab Navigators, all tabs display. Forcing you to nest navigators. Ho do I hide or display specific tabs?

Comment: Since I cant answer questions due to reputation, here is my own solution;

I made a npm package for that, check :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-selective-tab-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great thanks!

I was looking all over the place for something like this